# How to get the data-id of a div when i click on iframe which is inside that div

Tags: jquery

For one of my project, I have two divs with same class name, one has iframe when I click on iframe I want its div data-id. here is sample code. I used jquery. I am able to click inside iframe but when I get class it get data of first div not second one which I want. I try many way but I could not get any solutions. Please anyone help me. It will be great for me. Thanks in advance

```js
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLIFrameElement) {

    var ad_id = $(".abc", window.parent.document).attr('data-id');
    console.log(ad_id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc" data-id="125585"></div>
<div class="abc" data-id="144755">
  <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `window.parent.document` and your code works.

Comment: You can access the second element of the same class with `$(".abc")[1]`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I got my solution